# How to change log level in Akka-Http with Phantom

Tags: logging, akka, akka-http, phantom-dsl

I have a new project with **Akka-http 2.4.2** and **com.websudos.phantom** **1.22.0**
All works fine but I don't know how to change the log level to INFO so the DEBUG logs of phantom like:

> 17:00:51.792 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Connection -
>   Connection[/192.168.120.24:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] was
>   inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat 17:00:51.931
>
> [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection -
>   Connection[/192.168.120.24:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] heartbeat
>   query succeeded

and

> 17:07:27.387 [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] DEBUG
>   com.websudos.phantom - Executing query: SELECT * FROM
>   table1 WHERE user =
>   '1_1003600499' LIMIT 1;

**are ignore for console.**
Can I put this configuration in the file **application.conf**?. If so, **how?**
**RESOLUTION:**
As @flavian answered (and with little modification)
1) Create a file logback.xml in the resources folder
2) Copy and pase the following configuration

```
<configuration scan="false">
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -oijojj %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.websudos.phantom" level="WARNING"/>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>

</configuration>
```

This will make the logs only show **INFO level onwards** on the console

Comment: Slight comment, you are missing a closing </configuration> tag

Comment: thanks! @Nicolas Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phantom offers a SLF4J/Logback compatible API, meaning all you need to do is to provide the right `logback.xml` configuration in the resources folder of the module you want to configure.

Have a look at this.

```
<configuration scan="false">
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.websudos.phantom" level="WARNING">
  </logger>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you so much!!

Now with your help the heartbeat log doesn 't show more.
The "system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher" event log still is showing(the last log example), I think that may be I have to configure akka actors logging level, I'm not sure (still investigating)

Comment: Solution found!, I don' t know if is the cleanest one, please comment if a better one can be done. Again thanks @flavian